# Working with Django Project on gunicorn and Tornado

Tags: python, django, websocket, tornado, gunicorn

I've a `django` project running on `gunicorn server` behind an `nginx proxy`.

I would like to add real time chat functionality to this project and for this purpose I'm considering to use `Tornado websocket API`.
But the problem is, Chat messages needs to be authenticated by Django User as `request.is_authenticated()`. Similarily I need to use two Django models for handling Chat in tornado. I'm uanble to figure out how to handle this situation keeping both gunicorn and tornado server different.

I've considered few options:
1. Creating a dedicated API on gunicorn server that will listen to special messages from tornado server. This can be done but extra overhead will be on gunicorn server
2. Session authentication can be done via gunicorn server as API and rest of database handling can be done on tornado itself.

Are there better ways to handle this? Without creating API and integrating them seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run your Django app on top of tornado instead of gunicorn (see https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo). This isn't the best option for performance, but will let the django and tornado apps interact without building out a separate API.

Personally I recommend running django and tornado in the same process only as a stepping stone to transition to 100% tornado. If you intend to keep the django server then it is probably best to just build an authentication API that you can call from tornado.

Comment: Thanks, but while running django on the top of tornado, I'm having problem with django user. I'm unable to authenticate request and get django user from tornado WebSocketHandler. I tried your code from "https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/654157" but it isn't working with django 1.5 :(

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I haven't touched django in years so I can't help you with that one.